# How to make UITableView different colume on portrait and landscape?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swift

I need to present table view on iOS universal app (iPhone/iPad). I'm seeking a simple way to make different column on portrait and landscape

My target

```
iPhone portrait has 3 labels
iPad portrait has 6 labels
iPhone&iPad landscape has 6 labels
```

I should be programatically or use size classes or the other way ?

Please explain to me.

Thank you

Comment: Did you tried CollectionView to show Labels ? You Should SizeClasses and auto layout for your app to work on all devices easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
1) [[UIDevice current] userInterfaceIdiom] for determine iPhone or iPad

2) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] for determine current orientation
```

And via UIApplicationDelegate get events

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)newStatusBarOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)oldStatusBarOrientation;
```

Or you can subscribe on notifications in NSNotificationCenter

```
UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification; 
UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification; 
UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey;
```